# Find min/max hashCode values for string of a certain length

Tags: java, hash, range

Is there a way I can calculate the min/max hash code possible for a string of a certain length using Java's [.hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()) method?

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode()), the algorithm used is:

```
s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
```

... and it returns an `int`, which may be positive or negative.

Since it adds all the characters to compute the hash, I've tried finding the min/max hash by running `.hashCode()` on strings of the same length made up of the min/max character values (`space` = 32, `~` = 126), but I get values for `s` that are out of the range for my min/max hashes.

```
int s =       "hello world".hashCode();  // 1794106052

// strings the same len as "s"
int minHash = "           ".hashCode();  // 2142006304
int maxHash = "~~~~~~~~~~~".hashCode();  // -2034832962

// hash for s i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the string length is at least 6, then the minimum possible hashCode is `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and the maximum hashCode is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

That is, there is a string of length 6 that has a hashCode of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, and a string of length 6 that has a hashCode of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

You're seeing integer overflow, which is working as intended for `hashCode`.

Comment: Aha! That makes a lot of sense (I figured it was overflowing, just couldn't figure out where.) Can you tell me why that happens at 6 characters and not, say, at 5 or 7?

Comment: The first n where 126 * 31^(n-1) > Integer.MAX_VALUE is 6.

Comment: Gotcha. And how would I compute the min/max hash for strings with less than 6 characters?

Comment: The way you were doing it ought to suffice, just explicitly plugging in the min and max strings.  (All this said: hash codes really don't make sense to compare as "greater" or "less than," on the whole.)